# MySQL query with optional filter

Tags: php, mysql

I my table I have one column 'x' that is either 1 or 0. I need a MySQL query that returns either all rows, or those where x = 1 or where x = 0.

Which one of those threee results I want is set in a variable $type. What I did is create three queries and a if clause:

```
if ($type == 'all') $query = "SELECT * FROM contracts";
elseif ($type == 'n') $query = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE x = '0'";
elseif ($type == 'f') $query = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE x = '1'";
```

This works but I does not seem the best solution to me because I have to write 3 times an almost same query and if I want to change something I have to change it 3 times.

I tried to make $type = '', 0 or 1 and then `WHERE x = '$type'` but that did not work.

How would I do this using only one MySQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($type = 'all') {
    $filter = '';
} elseif ($type == 'n') {
    $filter = "WHERE x = '0'";
} elseif ($type == 'f') {
    $filter = "WHERE x = '1'";
} else {
    die("Invalid filter type: $type");
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM contracts $filter";
```

If you use the scheme where `$type = '', 0, or 1`, you can do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contracts";
if ($type !== '') {
    $query .= " WHERE x = '$type'";
}
```

Comment: Almost all answeres were good and similar. I chose this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($type){
    case 'n':
        $where = "WHERE x = '0'";
        break;
    case 'f':
        $where = "WHERE x = '1'";
        break;
    default:
        $where = "";
        break;
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM contracts '.$where;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM contracts';
if ($type != 'all')
    $query .= ' WHERE x = \'' . ($type == 'n' ? 0 : 1) . '\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contracts" . ($type != 'all' ? (" where x = '" . intval( $type == 'n') . "'") : '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a translation n to 0 and f to 1 etc, doing this inside the mysql query would require unnecessarily complex CASE statements. I prefer to include only the necessary string:

```
if ($type == 'all') $typeLimiter = " ";
elseif ($type == 'n') $typeLimiter = " AND x = '0' ";
elseif ($type == 'f') $typeLimiter = " AND x = '1' ";
```

This way you can stack unlimited AND/OR statements onto your query:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM contracts 
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    $typeLimiter";
```

Note that I include `WHERE 1 = 1` as the first statement so any/all/none of your limiters can be applied, or not.